# Which TLS version is Algolia PHP client using?

Tags: php, tls1.2, algolia

We have a PHP web application using Algolia PHP Client version 1.17 on our server, in the backend. Algolia is soon deprecating TLS 1.0 and 1.1 entirely.

How do I know which TLS version the PHP backend is using to contact Algolia? Is this strictly a web server configuration issue or is an SDK upgrade required?

Comment: "the php backend" is that your own developed PHP backend? what does it use? https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php ? then lookup the curl library used by checking the `phpinfo()` for the details. I assume that a newer library (php7.x + ) will be compliant...

Comment: @JoSSte yes that's our application, using the package as a dependency. I can see in there they're using curl to initiate the connection but they're not explicitly saying which TLS version to use

Comment: I would set up a simple server with letsencrupt and dissallow TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 and then trying code similar to what you have running towards algolia to that - if it works, your curl is fine...

Comment: you could also trwal throught he curl documentation to either find some debug flags, or explicitly set the protocol to use.

Comment: @JoSSte yeah I'm trying to find a way to "force" curl not to use anything below TLS 1.2, without having to mess around with 3rd party code

Comment: `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);` https://tecadmin.net/use-tls12-with-curl-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Algolia PHP API Client v1 uses a cURL client for network requests, which picks up the default system SSL version and appropriately leverages the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` options to enforce the security of the connection.

As long as you’re enforcing TLS 1.2 in your environment, you should be fine.